# How can I work out average of One person in same class when calling from Csv

Tags: python, csv

I have saved a score with a name in a csv. I would like to create an average score out of people names who are the same and display this.

```
score2 = str(score)#Converts the integer into the string so can be saved
fsav = (fulnam + " : " + score2)#Sets the variable as Full name of the user and the score  
filsav = clsnam + ".csv" #Creates the file that the scores will be saved in
file = open(filsav , "a") #Opens the file so it can be appended
file.write(fulnam + " , ") #Writes the persons name to the
file.write(score2) #Writes the persons score to the file 
file.write("\n")#Moves the file onto a new line
file.close() #Closes and saves the file
```

Comment: Do you have specific problem that we can solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, you have to read the entire file in to do it:

```
import csv

def compute_average(clsnam, fulnam):
    """ Determine average score in class for named person.
    """
    scores = []
    with open(clsnam + ".csv", 'r') as file:
        for name, score in csv.reader(file):
            if name.strip() == fulnam:
                scores.append(int(score))

    return None if not scores else float(sum(scores)) / len(scores)
```

Comment: How do I print the result?

Comment: The result of calling the function could be displayed with something like `print(compute_average('Biology101', 'Mary Jones'))`.